# Equalizer bar for muted audio

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create an audio equalizer through the guidance of [this tutorial](https://orangeable.com/javascript/equalizer-web-audio-api).
This works fine until you mute the audio through the controls(as shown in the image). Muting it also stops the equalizer bars.
How would I go about implementing the equalizer bars so that the bars don't stop even when the audio is muted?

```js
let canvas,
  ctx,
  source,
  context,
  analyser,
  fbc_array,
  bar_count,
  bar_pos,
  bar_width,
  bar_height;

let audio = new Audio();

audio.src = "test.mp3";
audio.controls = true; // Show audio controls so we can pause and play at will
audio.loop = true;
audio.autoplay = true;

window.addEventListener(
  "load", // only executes after loading page fully
  function() {
    document.getElementById("audio").appendChild(audio); // putting the audio element inside the another HTML element

    audio.onplay = function() {
      if (typeof(context) === "undefined") {
        context = new AudioContext();
        analyser = context.createAnalyser();
        canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); // returns a drawing context
        source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio); // creates an audio object which can be manipulated

        canvas.width = window.innerWidth * 0.80;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight * 0.60;

        source.connect(analyser);
        analyser.connect(context.destination); // connect the analyzer and the context(which is used to draw)
      }

      FrameLooper(); // will handle all the animation and output
    };
  },
  false
);

function FrameLooper() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(FrameLooper);

  fbc_array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount); // array for containing frequencies
  bar_count = window.innerWidth / 2;

  analyser.getByteFrequencyData(fbc_array);

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // clear old visual data
  ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff"; // fill it with white

  /* For repainting */
  for (let i = 0; i < bar_count; i++) {
    bar_pos = i;
    bar_width = 1;
    bar_height = -(fbc_array[i] / 2);

    ctx.fillRect(bar_pos, canvas.height, bar_width, bar_height);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

div#player {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 60vh;
  background: black;
  margin: 20vh auto 0px auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Equalizer bar</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="player">
    <div id="audio"></div>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>

</html>
```

[image: controls]

Comment: Please update your question with the CODE you have tried that reproducers the the specific challenge you have with that. FWIW many (including myself) will never click a link to somewhere else here.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Sorry for the inconveniance. I updated my question.

Comment: First off your HTML is invalid - `<script>` elements cannot be outside/after the end of the `</body>` tag.   That is not effecting the code presented since my assumption that is what is contained in in the `functions.js`.  I made a functional snippet of the code presented which does not seem to activate the "mute" when you click the speaker icon which is the major question asked herein thus does not seem to reproduce the issue here.

Comment: Quote MDN on `getByteFrequencyData`: _"Each item in the array represents the decibel value for a specific frequency"_ - So I am guessing - no volume, also means no decibel values? Not sure if what you want is possible, without playing the audio at least at some "tiny" volume.